# What's a word for "annoyingly posh"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> We were escorted into the old country club, and I made an instant grimace over how ______ the ambiance was."

Comment: decadent maybe, in the sense of luxurious indulgence? I love me some tobacco leather wingback chairs and good whiskey.

Comment: perhaps "lavish", "opulent" don't have enough of a negative connotation, but perhaps "grandiose" or "extravagant" would.

Comment: Is there any other kind of posh?

Answer (score 5):

> We were escorted into the old country club, and I made an instant grimace over how
>    **hoity-toity** the ambiance was.

Hoity-toity is synonymous with *[snobby](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/snobby)*, both terms  are related to *posh* and are derogative, so while a *posh* restaurant could be a compliment, and implies that is quite expensive to eat there; a *hoity-toity* restaurant will suggest it is run by a snobbish (or pretentious) management.

> [Hoity-toity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hoity-toity)
>   Haughty; snobbish:
>
> - *the moneyed, hoity-toity inhabitants of the island*
> - *They see people in the country as hoity-toity but nothing could be further from the truth,’ he said as we pulled into the driveway of his fifteenth-century home, Kilhenzie Castle*.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ostentatious

It can be used in proper context to deliver the intended meaning.